# How do I find if the roots of a quadratic equation are real and equal or real and unequal using the discriminant?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

If I have an equation such as $x^2+3x+4=0$, how do I find out whether the roots are real, rational, and equal or real, rational, and inequal using the discriminant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ the roots are:
$$
x_{1,2}=\dfrac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$

so you can easely see that:

1) if $D=b^2-4ac < 0$ there are no real roots ( the square root of a negative number is not a real number)

2) if $D=b^2-4ac = 0$ You have a real root $x=\dfrac{-b}{2a}$ or , better, we have two coincident real roots.

3) if $D=b^2-4ac > 0$ youfind two real distict roots and, if the coefficents $a,b,c$ are rational numbers the two roots are rational only if the quare root is a rational number, and this menas that $b^2-4ac$ must be  the square of a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

For $ a x^2 + b x + c= 0 $

Real and equal if $ b^2 - 4 a c = 0 $

Real and unequal if $ b^2 - 4 a c > 0 $

Complex conjugates if $ b^2 - 4 a c < 0 $

Comment: What about imaginary and irrational?

Comment: @SyedAffan The roots have imaginary parts in them iff $\Delta<0$. They are however not necessarily purely imaginary. Complex numbers are numbers of the form $m+ni$ for real $m,n$, where $m$ is the real part and $n$ is the imaginary part. Those numbers are called purely imaginary iff $m=0, n\neq 0$. The roots are purely imaginary iff the quadratic is of the form $ax^2+c=0$ and $\Delta<0$.

Comment: Whether the roots are rational depends on whether $\Delta$ is a square of a rational number.

Comment: Real numbers are complex too. $b^2-4ac<0$ is what gives complex numbers with imaginary parts in them.

Comment: @Indominus That is only true when the quadratic has rational coefficients.

Comment: @user26486, yes. But I assume the question is only interesting when all coefficients are integers (rationals, same thing). Otherwise, we'll also get into "what if the coefficients are complex" kinda mess.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so using $$D=b^2-4ac$$ with respective constants, you would say that *p* has real roots if $$D \geq 0$$
They are imaginary if $$D < 0$$
Addressing whether they are rational / irrational, use the algebra theorem that the root of any prime number is irrational, so if *D* is prime, then they are irrational.